# Load denied by X-Frame-Options : colorbox is not able to open PDF in iframe

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, iframe, colorbox

I am facing issue while opening PDF into colorbox iframe. Here is the approach which i have done so far..

Read file in FileInputStream and write it in OutputStream.

Java Code Snippet ..

```
            response.setContentType(imageContentType);
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int len = -1;
            while ((len = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

JSP ..

```
<a class='cboxPDF imguid cboxElement' href='/view/B2BSpineShippingAndPaymentComponentController?showHCPOFile=true&attachmentLocation=XXXX.pdf' />
```

JS ..

```
$(".cboxPDF").colorbox({
                    scrolling:  false,
                    iframe:true,
                    innerWidth:725,
                    innerHeight:545,
                    overlayClose: false,
                    onOpen: function(){
                        $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 0);
                        $(".page-loaderOverlay").show();
                    },
                    onComplete: function(){
                        $(".overlay").show();
                        $(".page-loaderOverlay").hide();
                        $("#colorbox").css("opacity", 1);
                    }               
                });
```

This above code is working fine on my local server. I can able to upload and check attached PDF in colorbox iframe.

But on host server, it is not working. Firebug is showing this exception

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://b2bssit.myorders.medtronic.com/view/B2BSpineShippingAndPaymentComponentController?showHCPOFile=true&attachmentLocation=PO_S002_S10000277003_1.pdf does not permit framing.
```

There are couple of things going on in my mind.

1. Is it a Infra team issue ( security on opening PDF in IFrame on this env)
2. Wrong X-Frame-Option. (Well we have set `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN">`)
3. Missing colorbox options.

I am not able to understand why it is working on my local but not on host server.

Please help.

Comment: You need to remove the `meta` tag. It stops the content of the page being opened in an iframe under another domain. It works locally because the security policy isn't applied to pages on your local machine.

Comment: We can't remove it. It is a project policy to add it for avoiding phishing attacks.

Comment: Then you need to find an alternative to an iframe, because this is the only way.

Comment: I tried removing meta tag from firebug but still problem persist